# Bug in pandas read_html method?

Tags: python, pandas

I think the [read_html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.html.read_html.html) method of pandas is buggy when dealing with rowspan and/or colspan.

Example:

```
html_table = io.StringIO(u'''<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Time</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Temp</th>
            <th colspan="3">Cloud Cover</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Low</th>
            <th>Middle</th>
            <th>High</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>22:00</td>
            <td>12C</td>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Ipsum</td>
            <td>Dolor</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>''')
```

The output of pd.read_html(html_table) is

```
[                 Time Temp Cloud Cover    Low Middle  High
 0 2014-05-16 22:00:00  12C       Lorem  Ipsum  Dolor   NaN

 [1 rows x 6 columns]]
```

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it just doesn't handle rowspan/colspan.  There is a previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791527/pandas-read-html-function-with-colspan-2) and an issue on the pandas tracker [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4679).

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks for pointing out the reported issue.

Comment: ?! That issue is about Excel, not html.

Comment: There's an open issue about this here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17054

Answer (score 0):

pandas >= 0.24.0 understands `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes. As per [the
release
notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#read-html-enhancements):

```
result = pd.read_html("""
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">1</td><td>2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>""")

result
```

Out:

```
[   A  B  C
 0  1  1  2
```

Previously this would return the following:

```
[   A  B   C
 0  1  2 NaN]
```